# How to turn off auto-equalization on Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows-10, audio, 64-bit, equalizer

Whenever there's a low loud note in a song or video that I'm listening to, the normal audio cuts off almost completely as to make the "loud" sound normalized. I hate this and can't stand having to constantly adjust the sound just so that I can have a normal listen to the song I'm listening to. There probably was a reason for the author to include that note or sound and I'm here to appreciate the whole song and not just this one note just because you thing that it was an "error". If something is too loud I'll remove my headphones thank you.
Any help is appreciated.

And no it's not in the enhancements tab or the driver.

Comment: What is your player?

Comment: Happens online and on Windows Media Player, VLC player and even Audacity

Comment: VLC player has an equalization plugin.

Comment: yea, but it's everywhere and I want it off

Comment: Each player will have its own mechanism, or not.

Comment: look, Audacity, if you didn't know, is an audio editing program and it would be quite helpful to know the true sound of anything you're hearing and not a "suggested" sound and that makes me believe that windows is doing the bad thing here, and not the programs.

Comment: I think the correct statement is that between the embedded player in Audacity, if you prefer it as an example, and Windows which also does part of the playing, you are in a bind.

Comment: Why is **Audacity** in your comment but not in your question.  I don't get the reference

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and resolved it by going to the properties of the affected audio device in the sound control panel, then selecting the advanced tab, and unchecking "Enable audio enhancements" and applying the changes.

Windows 10 22H2